# Run external application with no .exe extension

Tags: c#, .net, process

I know how to run an external application in C# `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(executableName);` but what if the application I want to run has extension that is not recognizable by Windows as extension of an executable. In my case it is `application.bin`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Key is to set the [`Process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute.aspx) property to `false` prior to starting the process, e.g.:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = @"c:\tmp\test.bin";
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute  = false;
p.Start();
```

This will start the process directly: instead of going through the "let's try to figure out the executable for the specified file extension" shell logic, the file will be considered to be executable itself.

Another syntax to achieve the same result might be:

```
var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = @"c:\tmp\test.bin",
    UseShellExecute = false
};
Process.Start(processStartInfo);
```

Comment: This ONLY works if you fully qualify the path to the file. If you leave it up to allowing Windows to search the PATH environment variable for the file, it will append an ".exe" for every folder it searches. Sadly, this is painful for the project I'm working on, because the location is entirely dependent on the `PATH` as set in a user file. I'll have to find the file manually and set the `StartInfo.FileName` property to a fully qualified path.

Comment: Ah...turns out there's a little old DOS trick you can you for this: Add a single period to the end of the file name and Windows will look for the file without an extension.  Set StartInfo.FileName="[appname]." and it will avoid adding the ".exe" at the end.

Answer (score 3):

And to follow on from @yelnic. Try using `cmd.exe /C myapp`, I found it quite useful when I want a little more out of `Process.Start()`.

```
using (Process process = Process.Start("cmd.exe") 
{
   // `cmd` variable can contain your executable without an `exe` extension
   process.Arguments = String.Format("/C \"{0} {1}\"", cmd, String.Join(" ", args));
   process.UseShellExecute  = false;
   process.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
   process.Start();
   process.WaitForExit();
   output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
}
```