# How do I start a non-executable process as an executable in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a system that downloads a file from my webserver as a .DLL. I would like to execute said DLL as an EXE file. Is there a way to start it directly as an EXE in C# or should I change it to an EXE and then run it.

EDIT: I am running Windows 10

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36516848/how-to-run-a-net-core-dll

Comment: Do you have any idea what a dll (dynamic link library) is?

Comment: Does your DLL have an entry point?  Like a `Main()` ?

Comment: My DLL is not actually a DLL; It does not have an entry point. The file is simply changed to a DLL for the streaming process.

Comment: @morsotom: Sorry, but your explanation makes no sense. If it's not actually a DLL (but an EXE file with its extension renamed), that would mean that it *does* have an entry point.

Comment: Does the answer to this question solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/q/3434799/87698

Comment: If you set `ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute` to false, the name/extension of your executable shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

solved it with this:
File.Move(DestinationPath, Path.ChangeExtension(DestinationPath, ".exe"));

Comment: Not what I was originally going for but it works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).